# Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 11 without USB Driver

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have a laptop windows preinstalled. I upgraded it to Windows 11 and I installed Ubuntu 20.04. Each time I reboot computer, it is automatically booting in Windows. I tried to change UEFI options but it did not work. Eventually, it worked when I plugged the USB driver which has been created by using Rufus. Is it possible to choose what I would like to use as OS after turning on the computer? If it is, how could I do this? Thank you in advance.

P.S. When with USB ubuntu is booting, it is not asking my password which I created for one ubuntu user and I realized every time it is creating a new ubuntu@ubuntu user. Because is asks me too install ubuntu and I click no then desktop appears and the changes I made before has gone totally new user "ubuntu@ubuntu". I'm totally sure I installed ubuntu because I can see in the installation section, it asks to remove all files in ubuntu and create new one. But I simply I cannot access to my ubuntu user which I created firstly. Does anyone struggle this ?

Comment: `I tried to change UEFI options but it did not work` -- What options did you change?

Comment: I changed UEFI mode to Legacy Support. Also i disabled the Secure mode. But it did not work as I told.

Comment: You can't change to legacy otherwise Windows will not boot, at all, and there's no way to make it boot because **Windows 11 does NOT support Legacy mode nor disabling Secure Boot**. Where you should've changed is at the **Boot menu** > OS selection or something similar.

Comment: @ChanganAuto do you know how to select OS selection? I though it is only possible thanks to EasyBCD. That is why I am trying to get Legacy mode.

Comment: EasyBCD is for BIOS/Legacy only! Stop using it at once! In any case the equivalent is EasyUEFI. And no, it's not needed, as long as you can (and you should) open the UEFI settings, navigate to Boot menu and there choose "Ubuntu" instead of "Windows bootloader manager". Sorry to say, this is very basic stuff. If you don't know this you should learn it trough before installing OSes. Very soon ALL new hardware won't even have "Legacy Mode" so there's that.

Comment: Rufus has an option to use a GPT (non CSM), Partition scheme when creating a Live USB. This should work with Windows UEFI boot. Remove Windows drive before installing Ubuntu using the GPT USB. Reinstall the windows drive, boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`. You should then be able to run either Windows or Ubuntu from the GRUB menu.